# How can I get my application running time?

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-7

How to find out the time that my application is running since it started?

Comment: CPU time? If not, note the time at startup then subtract from the current time whenever you need it..

Comment: Define "running". Does that mean "how long in days/hours/minutes/seconds since it was started", or does it mean "how much time has it actually been doing something that uses the CPU instead of minimized or just sitting there"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

function FileTime2DateTime(FileTime: TFileTime): TDateTime;    //Convert then FileTime to TDatetime format
var
  LocalTime: TFileTime;
  DOSTime  : Integer;
begin
  FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTime, LocalTime);
  FileTimeToDosDateTime(LocalTime, LongRec(DOSTime).Hi, LongRec(DOSTime).Lo);
  Result := FileDateToDateTime(DOSTime);
end;

Var
  lpCreationTime, lpExitTime, lpKernelTime, lpUserTime: TFileTime;

begin
  try
    GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess,lpCreationTime, lpExitTime, lpKernelTime, lpUserTime);
    Sleep(1000); //do something

    Writeln(Format('Running Time %s',[FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz',Now-FileTime2DateTime(lpCreationTime))]));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Things are easier now that we can forget about Windows 95/98.